# Minusing 2 Dates and Int in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a time sheet in Sharepoint.
Its a custom list with these columns (simplified form shown here)

```
Date work started (30/06/2011) [date]
Time Work Started (0800)    [24 hour clock / number]
Break Time        (30)      [minutes]
Time Work Stopped (1500)    [24 Hour Clock /number]
Total Hours Worked [Calculated by work stopped - work started - break time]
```

I could possibily change it so time started and time finished were date/times but that would mean i would have to enter the dates twice? However I also do not know a formula I could use to work out the Hours:minutes of total worked.

So im not sure which i sthe easiest way, and I cant figure out any forumula to work out the total hours worked (it would need to show hours:minutes like that) or hours.hours.

so either 7:00 or 7.00  for 7 hours 0 minutes
or 7:30 or 7.50  for 7 hours 30 minutes